Socks5 Proxy not working with Titanium.Web.Proxy library
I am using the Titanium.Web.Proxy library to set up a proxy connection in the format host:port:username:password and convert it to IPlocal:port. The HTTPS proxy works correctly, but the Socks5 proxy does not.
When I test the Socks5 proxy, it returns the local IP address instead of routing through the proxy. What am I missing or doing wrong in my implementation? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the relevant code for starting the Socks5 proxy:
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Titanium.Web.Proxy;
using Titanium.Web.Proxy.EventArguments;
using Titanium.Web.Proxy.Models;
using System.Net;
using System;

namespace XXXXX
{
    internal class Titanium
    {
        private ProxyServer proxyServer;
        private string remoteHost;
        private int remotePort;
        private string remoteUser;
        private string remotePass;


        public Titanium(string remoteHost, int remotePort, string remoteUser, string remotePass)
        {
            this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
            this.remotePort = remotePort;
            this.remoteUser = remoteUser;
            this.remotePass = remotePass;
            proxyServer = new ProxyServer();
            proxyServer.BeforeRequest -= OnBeforeRequest;
            proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnBeforeRequest;
            proxyServer.BeforeResponse += OnBeforeResponse;
        }
        public bool IsRunning => proxyServer?.ProxyRunning ?? false;
        private Task OnBeforeRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsBypassed(e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.Host))
                {
                    e.CustomUpStreamProxy = new ExternalProxy
                    {
                        HostName = remoteHost,
                        Port = remotePort,
                        UserName = remoteUser,
                        Password = remotePass,
                        ProxyType = ExternalProxyType.Socks5
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                   e.CustomUpStreamProxy = null;
                }
                Log($"BeforeRequest: {e.HttpClient.Request.Url}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"OnBeforeRequest Error: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task OnBeforeResponse(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Log($"BeforeResponse: {e.HttpClient.Request.Url}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"OnBeforeResponse Error: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }


        public bool StopProxy()
        {
            if (this.proxyServer != null)
            {

                var endPointsToRemove = new List<ProxyEndPoint>      (this.proxyServer.ProxyEndPoints);


                foreach (var endPoint in endPointsToRemove)
                {
                    this.proxyServer.RemoveEndPoint(endPoint);
                }

                this.proxyServer.Stop();
                this.proxyServer = null;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool StartHttpProxy(int localPort)
        {
            try
            {
                var endPoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort, false);
                proxyServer.AddEndPoint(endPoint);

                proxyServer.BeforeRequest -= OnBeforeRequest;
                proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnBeforeRequest;

                proxyServer.Start();

                Log("HTTP Proxy started");

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"HTTP Proxy Error: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool StartSocks5Proxy(int localPort)
        {
            try
            {
                var endPoint = new SocksProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort, false);
                proxyServer.AddEndPoint(endPoint);

                proxyServer.BeforeRequest -= OnBeforeRequest;
                proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnBeforeRequest;

                proxyServer.Start();

                Log("Socks5 Proxy started");

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"Socks5 Proxy Error: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

